# How can i use QueryString with Sharepoint list programmatically?

Tags: query-string

I want to pull datas from list with queries. I want to use many queries with C# code. And there is QueryString in C#. I want to use it. So how can i do this.

Comment: are you trying to use it in App ? or Visual Web Part ? that is Client side Object model or Server Object Model

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Visual Web Part and placed it in a page called http://myspsite/pages/WebPart.aspx then form the url with passing the Query String Parameter like

```
http://myspsite/pages/WebPart.aspx?MyParam=test
```

then to get this value from web part page PageLoad function call

```
string myParam = Request.QueryString["MyParam"];
```

this will give you the passed value in the query string. then you can pass this values in CamlQuery filters dynamically to retrieve list items.

Answer (score 2):

Use Request.QueryString to get querystring.

```
Request.QueryString["parameter1"];
```

Build your query with dynamic values.

Sample code:

Server side object model:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                query.Query = @"<Where><And>
                                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='ProjectCode' /><Value Type='Text'>"+queryValue+@"</Value></Eq>
                                    <And>
                                        <Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' LookupId='True' /><Value Type='Int'>" + user.ID + "</Value></Eq>" + @"
                                        <Or><IsNull><FieldRef Name='TriggerFromTimerJob' /></IsNull><Eq><FieldRef Name='TriggerFromTimerJob' /><Value Type='Choice'>NO</Value></Eq></Or>
                                    </And>
                                </And></Where>";
```

Client Side CAML:

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
            query.ViewXml = @"<View><Query>
                                <Where>
                                    <Eq><FieldRef Name='users' /><Value Type='User'>" + queryValue + @"</Value></Eq>
                                </Where>
                               </Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
```

SharePoint CAML schema

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521.aspx